# Laplacian as a limit of a volume integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've found this in a book

$$
\nabla^2f=\lim_{R\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{V(B_{R}(\vec{r}))}\oint_{\delta B_{R}(\vec{r})}\frac{\partial f}{\partial n} dS
$$
Where $V(B_{R}(\vec{r}))$ is the volume of the ball of radius $R$ with center at $\vec{r}$. And it says it can be proven using Green's identities but really I couldn't approach to that. I've found here it can be obtained using Tylor's expansion but the chapter is about Green's identities so it would be better to know how they get that above from the Green's identities.
Thank you

Comment: Use Divergence theorem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the definition of the divergence to prove something equivalent.

By definition $\nabla^2f=\nabla \cdot \nabla f$.

From $df=\nabla f \cdot d\vec{s}$, defining the gradient, one can derive the gradient in arbitrary coordinates. Then apply the definition of the divergence.

$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}= \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{\oint\vec{E}\cdot \hat{n} dS}{\Delta V}$

Then let $\vec{E}=\nabla f$.

$df = \sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i $ by the chain rule.

$d\vec{s}=\sum_ih_i(\vec{x})dx_i\hat{e_i}$ by definition of the Line Element.

$df=\nabla f\cdot d\vec{s}\implies \nabla f_i=\frac{1}{h_i(\vec{x})}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\hat{e_i}$

$\nabla^2f = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0}\frac{\int \frac{1}{h_i(\vec{x})} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} h_j(\vec{x})h_k(\vec{x}) dx_jdx_k}{\int h_ih_jh_kdx_idx_jdx_k}=\sum_i\frac{1}{h_i(\vec{x})}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\frac{1}{h_i(\vec{x})}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}h_j(\vec{x})h_k(\vec{x}))$

As I recall,  you can work a Greens Funciton argument into that format.